# Use Blumenthal's 0-1 law to solve the following

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, brownian-motion, limsup-and-liminf

From Durett: $B(t)$ represents a Brownian motion,

"$(i)$ Suppose $f(t) > 0$ for all $t>0$. Use Blumenthal's $0-1$ law to conclude that $\lim \sup_{t \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{B(t)}{f(t)} = c$, $P_0$ a.s., where c is a constant in $[0,\infty]$.

$(ii)$ Show that if $f(t) = \sqrt{t}$ then $c=\infty$, so with probability one Brownian Paths are not Holder continuous of order $1/2$ at $0$"

I understand that the random variable $\lim \sup_{t \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{B(t)}{f(t)}$ is in the germ sigma field thus we can apply Blumenthal's $0-1$ law to all events involving it.

$(ii)$ We need to show that $P_0(\lim \sup_{t \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{B(t)}{\sqrt{t}} \leq s) = 0$, $\forall s \in \mathbb{R}$. By Blumenthal's $0-1$ law this is equivalent to $P_0(\lim \sup_{t \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{B(t)}{\sqrt{t}} \leq s) < 1$, $\forall s \in \mathbb{R}$

$P_0(\lim \sup_{t \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{B(t)}{\sqrt{t}} \leq s) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_0(\sup_{t \leq 1/n} \frac{B(t)}{\sqrt{t}} \leq s) \leq P_0(\frac{B(1/n)}{\sqrt{1/n}} \leq s) = \Phi(s) < 1 $

Where the last equality comes from the fact that $\frac{B(t)}{\sqrt{t}} \sim N(0,1)$

(i) I can't find a similar way to deal with this one, any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every set in a sigma field has probability 0 or 1 then any function measurable with respect to it is almost surely constant. To prove this just note that the distribution function $F$ of this random variable has the property that $F(x)$ is 0 or 1 for every $x$. It is fairly easy to show that if $a=\inf \{x:F(x)=1\}$ then $F(x)=0$ for $x<a$ and 1 for $x \geq a$. Hence the function is almost surely equal to $a$.

Comment: I agree but how to conclude that c can't be negative ? Even if $f(t)$ is positive $B(t)$ can take negative value

Comment: I do not know an elementary way of showing that $c \geq 0$ but there are several theorems that guarantee this. One is "Law of iterated logarithm at 0": Corollary 31, section 19.8  of "A Modern Approach to Probability Theory" by Fristedt and Gray. I am quoting this particular result because I think it is very nice and very useful result.

Comment: $P_0(\lim \sup_{t \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{B(t)}{f(t)} \geq 0) \geq \lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} P_0(\frac{B(t)}{f(t)} \geq 0) =  \lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} P_0(B(t) \geq 0) > 0 $ so by Blumenthal's 0-1 law, $\exists c \in [0,\infty]$ such that $P_0(\lim \sup_{t \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{B(t)}{f(t)} = c) = 1$

Does it solve properly the problem ? And thank you for the reference about the Law of iterated logarithm.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy there is a very easy way to see that $c=+\infty$ a.s. without using anything as strong as the law of the iterated logarithm. See the answer below.

Comment: @Shalop My answer was only for the first part where it is not given that $f(t)=\sqrt t$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ok, and my comment is referring to your previous comment where you say "I do not know of an elementary way...." I may be wrong, but it seems as though this is the true content of the question anyways.

Comment: @ Shalop my earlier comment was also about the first part.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an easy way of seeing that $c=+\infty$ almost surely, in the case that $f(t) = \sqrt t$.

Indeed, note that $B_t/\sqrt{t}$ has a $N(0,1)$ distribution for all $t$, hence $P(B_t/\sqrt t>M)=c>0$ for all $M>0$ and $t>0$.

By "reverse Fatou's lemma", it holds that $$P\bigg( \limsup_{t\to 0} \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}} >M\bigg) = E \big[ \limsup_{t \to 0} 1_{\{t^{-1/2}B_t >M\}}\big] \geq \limsup_{t \to 0} P\big( B_t/\sqrt{t}>M)=c>0. $$Now apply Blumenthal to conclude that the probability must be $1$.

Comment: Is Fatou's Lemma valid for $t \to 0$?

Comment: Of course, Fatou's lemma and its reverse are valid along any limit. Even if you are skeptical, you can just replace the $\lim_{t \to 0}$ with any deterministic sequence $t_n \downarrow 0$.

Comment: you are wrong. limsup as $t \to 0$ cane be replaced by limisup along a sequence only for a particular $\omega$ and the sequence will depend on $\omega$. Rudin once thought Egoroff's Theorem holds for $f_t \to f$ as $t \to \infty$ but someone gave a counter example in AMM.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I am not wrong. Fatou's lemma is still true along continuous limits (as long as the limit is measurable) and the proof is simple. For instance, take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959145/continuous-time-version-of-fatous-lemma?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). But (for humour's sake) even if you don't believe that result, you can just replace $t$ here with $t_n \downarrow 0$, then replace the $\limsup_{t \to 0}$ with $\limsup_{n \to \infty}$ and apply the "usual" Fatou's lemma.

Comment: thanks for the reference.